# ShinyApp:Why do the outcomes change in ggplot when more than one input is selected?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, rstudio, reactive-programming

I am creating a *ShinyApp* for a yearly performance assessment of various workers and would like to show the performance (salespermonth) of one or multiple workers(W) based on the input selected. However, I am experiencing changing values for the same "W" when more than one "W" is selected in the sidebarPanel. Does anyone know why?

There somehow seems to be a problem with the reactive function of `data.b`, more precisely the part, where `ID==input$ID`.

`data.frame` sample (ID goes from 1-10):

```
  ID Calendartime timewithfirm salespermonth cumm.sales
1  1   2006-01-01            3           800        800
2  1   2006-02-01            3           300       1100
3  1   2006-03-01            3           150       1250
4  1   2006-04-01            3           200       1450
5  1   2006-05-01            3           350       1800
6  1   2006-06-01            3           100       1900
```

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar( 
headerPanel(title=h1("Worker Performance Assessment", align="center")),

sidebarPanel(

uiOutput("chooseW"),
dateRangeInput("daterange", label = h3("Date range"),start = "2006-01-01",end   = "2006-12-01",format = "yyyy/mm/dd", separator="-"),  
submitButton(text="Update!")
) ,
mainPanel(
plotOutput("salesplot")
)

) 
)
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales) # for formatting date scales in ggplot

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

output$chooseW <- renderUI({
IDs<- dataframe$ID
selectInput("ID", label=h3("Choose a Worker"), IDs, 1 , multiple = TRUE)
 }) 

 # reactive function for plot
 data.b = reactive({
 b= subset(dataframe,Calendartime %in% (input$daterange[1]:input$daterange[2]) & ID == input$ID)
  return(b)
  })

 output$salesplot <- renderPlot({
 cc<- data.b() 
 q= ggplot(cc, aes(x=Calendartime,y=salespermonth, group=ID, colour=ID)) + 
  geom_line() +scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks("1 month"),labels = date_format("%b"))
print(q)

})   
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. The problem comes in the line with `ID == input$ID`. You just need to change that to `ID %in% input$ID` in your subsetting line in the server.R. The problem will then be solved. The point here is that the `input$ID` is not just one value but a vector of length > 1 in case you have multiple selection.